# Como añadir una imagen a una lista?

Tags: css3

Hola tengo el siguiente código en el cual debo agregarle una PNG que me dio el cliente, las PNG las debo agregar a las li del menú, alguien sabe como podría hacer eso o como convertirlas a iconos?

MI CÓDIGO ACTUAL:

```css
 
body{
   font-size:20px;
   text-align:justify;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
.nav-wrapper{
  background:#ff7334;
}

.nav-content{
  background:#0D0D0D;
}

.page-footer{
  height:505px;
    background:#000000;

}

.contactoinfo{
  color:#F2F2F2;
}
.tarjetas{
  color:#fff;
}

/*En esta linea tengo error no se agrega la imagen a la lista a ninguna*/
li{
list-style-image:url(img/iconos/Baños.png);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Lovi acabados</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.8" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-translate@*" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.5.0/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

<!-- -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $('.tap-target').tapTarget('open');
  $('.tap-target').tapTarget('close');
</script>

  <body ng-controller="translateController">
<div ng-controller="translateController" class="nav-wrapper">
    <button class="color-idiomas waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')">English </button>

    <button class="color-idiomas waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('sp')">Spanish</button>

    </div>
<nav class="default" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                  <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Lovi Acabados</a>

      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="side-nav">
          <li><a  href="producto1.html">Adoquin</a></li>
      <li><a  href="producto2.html">Azulejo</a></li>
        <li ><a  href="producto3.html">Barro</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto4.html">Block</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto5.html">Cantera</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto6.html">Esculturas reducidas</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto7.html">Fuentes</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto8.html">Granito</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto9.html">Iluminación</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto10.html">Jacuzzi</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto11.html">Ladrillo refractario</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto12.html">Mármol</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto13.html">Piedras decorativas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto15.html">Piso</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto17.html">Sanitarios</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto16.html">Tejas</a></li>      </ul>

        
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                  <li><a  href="producto1.html">Adoquin</a></li>

      <li><a  href="producto2.html">Azulejo</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto3.html">Barro</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto4.html">Block</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto5.html">Cantera</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto6.html">Esculturas reducidas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto7.html">Fuentes</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto8.html">Granito</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto9.html">Iluminación</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto10.html">Jacuzzi</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto11.html">Ladrillo refractario</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto12.html">Mármol</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto13.html">Piedras decorativas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto15.html">Piso</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto17.html">Sanitarios</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto16.html">Tejas</a></li>      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: a que te refieres con añadirlos a la `<li>` actual?

Comment: perdon a este -->           <li><a  href="producto1.html">Adoquin</a></li>

Comment: Quiero agregarle de fondo a ese li una imagen pero no se pone o como biñeta pero tampoco

Answer (score 0):

```css
li{
display: inline-block;
background-image: url(https://matematicasparaticharito.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/cuadrado.png?w=217&h=216);
}
```

```html
<li>Prueba</li>
```

Esto funciona para mi como verás en el ejemplo, para que no se repita he puesto el `inline-block`